# How to evaluate if $\int_2^\infty {\frac{1}{\log(x)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+1}}}dx$ converges?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I am asked to evaluate if $$\int_2^\infty {\frac{1}{\log(x)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+1}}}dx$$ 
converges.

How can that be done? Even Wolframalpha/Mathematica 8.0 does not return a value.

Can this be done with improper integral convergence tests I,II or III?

EDIT:

Improper integral convergence test I (I guess it is also called comparison test I, at least in my native language):

If there exists $g(x)$ such that $0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)\quad \forall x \in [a;=\infty)$

and  $\int_a^\infty{g(x)dx}$ converges, then $\int_a^\infty{f(x)dx}$ also converges.

Improper integral convergence test II would be the ratio test.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. As a new user, please see this post on how to ask a good question on this site, particularly the part about including context: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @Carl I am inclined to give the OP the benefit of the doubt here - although the question could be better, the last two lines show that they have thought about it a bit. Although I have no idea what "improper integral convergence tests I,II or III" are. Perhaps the OP could clarify?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$\int_{2}^{M}\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\int_{\log 2}^{\log M}\frac{dt}{t}=\log\log M-\log\log 2$$
and for any $x\geq 2$:
$$\frac{1}{\log(x)\cdot\sqrt{x^2+1}}\geq\frac{1}{x\log x\cdot\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{x\log x}$$
the integral is divergent.

Comment: I understand the first integral, but how did you came up with $\frac{1}{\log{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}}\geq \frac{1}{x \log{x}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}}$?

Comment: @KristiansKuhta:  Since $x\geq 2$, $$\sqrt{x^2+1}=x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\leq x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}}.$$

Comment: Ok, I see now, thank you!

Comment: Simpler: $\sqrt{x^2+1}<\sqrt{x^2+x^2}=x\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.  First investigate
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log x}\ .$$

Comment: So I evaluate this ($\int_2^\infty{\frac{dx}{x\log{x}}}=\infty$), then concider $g(x)=\frac{dx}{x\log{x}}$ and calculate $lim_{x->\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$ and if its a real number, then integral diverges, right?

Comment: That will do it (as long as the limit is not zero).